# Java listens to file open event

Tags: java, file, events, monitor

I want to monitor millions of files and log what was exactly changed, say , "file [1.txt], line[123], from [Param1=true] to  [param1=false]"

so I plan to listen to file open event and make a original copy in memory, so that I can compare it with the one on file-system after the modification event , but I don't find any existing API or 3rd-party library  that can capture file open event.
WatchService API covers create, update and delete but not open.
anything else i can turn to? or maybe I'm in a wrong direction in fulfilling the requirement?

Comment: Do you care about external un-related processes that open and change files, or just other components running in your same JVM that are doing it? What operating system are you using?

Comment: By the time you’re notified that the file is opened, it might be to late to copy it. It might be better to make a copy of the file when it’s changed

Comment: The change is made from outside the same JVM, in fact, it is even not necessarily made by a Java process.  Basically , what I want to implement is a standalone platform-independent monitor.

Comment: yes, it is too late to copy the file when I'm notified. What I need is a OS level     file system hook with which I can be notified that some file is potentially being changed, and I can get a copy ready for a diff calculation when file is actually  modified. so question is, is there any library of OS level hook?